# Play store invalid apk signature flutter (APK integrity check failed)

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, admob, apk

When I upload the apk to the google play dev console I get this error:

> You uploaded an APK with an invalid signature (learn more about signing). Error from apksigner: ERROR (APK Signature Scheme v2 signer #0): APK integrity check failed. CHUNKED_SHA256 digest mismatch. Expected: <412a79e056b386dd932da2bc4dd539b8c4c91218f11732c9dc1238102f9ccdd0>, actual: <5cc9552be9c67af6a8c1f24f0cee15ef4b1305f0c5b56fbfee9f0f9c228e5828>

I tried running: `flutter build apk` in the terminal.
I also tried opening the project for editing in android studio and going to `Build >> Generate signed bundle(s) / apk(s)`. And chose both V1 & V2.

I created a new key and created a `key.properties` file containing:

```
storePassword=********
keyPassword=********
keyAlias=upload
storeFile=D:\\projects\\keys\\upload-keystore.jks
```

I didn't put the password here but it's written directly without quotes. And if it was wrong I'll get an error.

I have this in the `build.gradle` app-level file:

```
...
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}
...
..
...
signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
...
```

I'm using AdMob in the app.
When I run `java --version` I get:

> java 15.0.1 2020-10-20

But in my android installation path `/jre/release` file I have:

> JAVA_VERSION="11.0.8"

So I tried making a new key in android studio and a new signed apk in android studio just in case it depends on the java version used, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I uploaded an .apk file signed with another key before this one and even though I deleted that release, google registered that key for future uploads. I could see it in the App Integrity section. So I had to delete the whole app and make another store listing from scratch. Because I no longer have access to that old key.